# Why is terminal takes so long to start? C++

Tags: c++, terminal, division

Actually i am a beginner in C++. I have been trying to write a code that can divide any number using very basic operations and producing the non-decimal quotient and remainder. But when i build and run the terminal (CodeBlocks) it takes a minute or two for the terminal to run. I have tried using arrays but no use.

Please tell me any improvement, but i donnt want to use any additional header files. Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){


 double a, b, x, y;
 int n=0;

cout<<"x\n-\ny\n\nEnter x: ";
cin>>x;
cout<<"\nEnter y: ";
cin>>y;

while (n>=0){

a=x-(y*n);
b=x-(y*(n+1));

if(b<0)break;
if(b<a) n++;    }

cout<<"\nQuotient: "<<n<<"\n\nRemainder: "<<a;

}
```

Comment: Most likely, you have antivirus software that spends a long time analysing your code - try turning off your AV software.

Comment: Which hardware are you using? Processor, RAM memory and Hard Disk.

Comment: @Alexandre Borela: I am having core i3 3.30 GHz, 4Gb ram and 500 gb hdd

Comment: @RohanSahaTurai Could be lack of ram, specially as Mats mentioned if you have an anti virus running. Also, when your computer tries to go beyond the 4GB, it uses the Paging File (your HD) which is a lot slower. One easy way to check if you need more ram, disable the Paging File, if for some reason you use all the available RAM, you'll see applications closing for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be the program itself. Check for [Code Completion](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=11715.0) slowness.

Some good suggestions to add:

1. Turn off all Plug-ins you do not use.
2. Run Code::Blocks as Admin
3. Turn off code completion to see if the problem goes away.
4. Use a nightly build

Comment: Srry but what's a nightly build?

Answer (score 0):

It all runs fine for me.

The compiling time might be the thing that's bugging you.
Maybe don't rebuild the whole project when you just want to run the program.

I believe pressing F9 is "Build and run" and Ctrl + F10 is just "Run".

Also, n will never be less than 0 so rethink the conditional in you while loop.

Comment: Yes i am aware that n will never be zero. But just to get a loop I have used this condition. I have used the break statement to stop. Is this condition the problem? Plss  can u suggest any better looping option?

Comment: After compilation an exe file will made that will rebuild every time.. So doesn't help.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that if you don't change the code and just want to test your program with other input you don't have to compile it because it takes time. Build usually means compile. I am losing my certainity of what you mean by your questions.

Comment: Nah it's ok... Thanks 